# Append Kernel.local_variables to scope of binding

Tags: ruby, scope, read-eval-print-loop

I've made a rudimentary REPL for a software which has the ability to run ruby scripts. I want to be able to pass the variables from the previous scope to the REPL on launch, so I can easily debug my code.

```
def launchREPL(locals)
    puts "\"Starting REPL...\""
    __b = binding   #Evaluating in a binding, keeps track of local variables
    __s = ""
    __b.local_variables = locals  ## <-- ERROR OCCURS HERE
    bStartup = true
    while bStartup || __s != ""
        # If startup required skip evaluation step
        if !bStartup

            #Evaluate command
            begin
                __ret = __s + "\n>" + __b.eval(__s).to_s
            rescue 
                __ret = __s + "\n> Error: " + $!.to_s
            end
            puts __ret
        else
            #REPL is already running
            bStartup = false
        end

        #Read user input & print previous output
        __s = Application.input_box(__ret,"Ruby REPL","")
        __s == nil ? __s = "" : nil
    end
end
```

The above is my code to launch the REPL. The idea is that I would be able to do:

```
launchREPL(Kernel.local_variables)
```

and then be able to access all the local variables from the previous scope inside the REPL.

However I get the error `'local_variables' of '__b' is not defined`. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the problem is that there is no `Binding#local_variables=` method, there is just reader [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variables). Can you use `Binding#local_variable_set` to append new values?

Comment: @Aleksey I was wondering that also. I did try `__b.local_variable_set` but apparently that method was undefined. However just tried `__b.eval("locals = #{locals}")` and that seems to work fine. However, slight problem... `Kernel.local_variables` appears to return the names of the variables and not the value of the variables...

Comment: you can get  the value of variable via `Binding#local_variable_get` or with `eval` on binding.

Comment: But what is binding in this case? Like this `launchREPL(Binding#local_variable_get)`?

Comment: By `Binding` I mean Ruby class, the instance of which you can get calling `Kernel#binding` method.

Comment: Right I see. Will work on it.  can also access everything by passing Kernel directly into launchREPL

Comment: the methods are private so I can't access them...

Answer (score 0):

A bit of testing later and I came up with this:

```
__b.eval("locals = #{locals}")
```

However... I've realized that this just returns the names of the local variables and not the values of the variables...